# Rename a column of a df obtained from the sapply function

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply

so, i've used the function sapply to calculate the mean of dataframe's column according to various version with this command:

```
p <- sapply(split(testResults$SeverityScore, testResults$version), mean)
```

obtaining:

```
1.4.1      1.5    1.5.1    1.5.2    1.5.4      1.6    1.6.1    1.6.2    1.6.3    
29.40580 36.16129 37.13684 37.13684 37.62500 74.04167 74.13529 81.99457 84.97895
```

The problem is when i try to convert this list to a dataframe, where i obtain the right column with the wanted means, but i can't access the first column because is set as "default" as in the image:

[image].

All what i want is to convert the result obtained from the sapply function into a dataframe with 2 column: version and p

Comment: Looks like you can use a dplyr solution: `library(dplyr)` `testResults %>% group_by(version) %>% summarise(SeverityScore=mean(SeverityScore))` may give you what you're looking for

Comment: exactly what i wanted; thanks a lot @CPak